# Silverlight DataGrid Header Horizontal Alignment

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I want to change the alignment of a header on a datagrid in Silverlight, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Here's what I have so far:

```
  <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="#" 
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignStyle}" 
                            Binding="{Binding OutlineNumber, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="prim:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
    </data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
  </data:DataGridTextColumn>
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to change the default alignment, which appears to be "left."

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Any luck with this yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were really close, its:-

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
```

Comment: Actually, this does work! I didn't realize it because I wasn't resizing the column to see that the text does stay aligned to the right on the header. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add padding to make it look better...

```
    <Style x:Key="HeaderCenter"
           TargetType="dataPrimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="12,2,2,2" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this approach sorta works but you get the default header, right aligned.  I have a static resource style for the datagridcolumnheader and I **only** want to change the alignment leaving all the other style elements as contained in the custom style.
So far I have:

`xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"

xmlns:prim="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"`

and

```
<sdk:DataGrid  x:Name="ServicesDataGrid" Width="Auto" Margin="15,5,5,5" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}" ......
```

and

`<sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Gross Amt"  Binding="{Binding GrossAmount,StringFormat=n2}"    ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}">
   <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="prim:DataGridColumnHeader">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
     </Style>
   </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</sdk:DataGridTextColumn>`

Resizing the grid shows the text is right aligned but the font, background, etc are not as defined in DataGridColHeaderStyle

Thanks