# Display Datagrid horizontally Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datagrid

I am working on a Silverlight 5 project which uses a DataGrid contorl.
I want to display the data inside grid horizontally. I took reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426954/silverlight-datagrid-header-horizontal-alignment).

I was able to use the LayoutTransformer and datagrid was rotated. However I am facing a small issue.

```
Issue: The Cell headers are vertically displayed.
```

[image]

I want these cell headers to be displayed horizontally. I tried modifying the Header Style. Was able to rotate the headers but the header text is clipped becase the surrounding rectangle is not enlarged.

[image]

Here is the XAML code I have written

```
 <Style x:Key="GridHeader" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Background" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Silver" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Border
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      CornerRadius="2">
                            <ContentControl
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                          FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                          IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                                <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
                                </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

<!-- Code for 1 column. Similarly I have added more columns to the DataGrid-->

<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IPTV12MISTarget" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GridHeader}" >
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                    <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                    </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IPTV12MISTarget}" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                    <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                    </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding IPTV12MISTarget, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"></TextBox>
                                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Question: How should I enlarge Header rectangle to display full header content?**

Comment: So you have a `RenderTransform` in your `GridHeader` template flipping it 90º, then another `LayoutTransform` in each `CellTemplate` flipping it 90º which is a little confusing, but for your current issue I would expect just adding `Width="Auto"` by your Header declaration should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `RenderTransform`, use a [`LayoutTransformer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.internal.pivot.controls.layouttransformer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead (included in SL5, was part of the toolkit prior to Silverlight5).
So where you have this now:

```
<ContentControl ...>
    <ContentControl.RenderTransform> ...90...</ContentControl.RenderTransform>
</ContentControl>
```

write

```
<LayoutTransformer>
    <LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    <LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
    <ContentControl .../>
</LayoutTransformer>
```